# Problem with integrating exponential function in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I'm trying to calculate the finite integral for the [CDF of the normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function), when I plug the equation into Wolfram Alpha and integrate

> exp((-t^2)/2) dt from -inf to 1000000

I get: 2.5 (for just the integral), when I run the same equation through R I get 0. On further digging I think the discrepency lies with the 'exp' function. I'm guessing that means I'm doing something wrong or I missed a step somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually is because numerical integration has difficulty when only a relatively small part of the space between the ranges is substantially different from zero; it has trouble finding that portion of the range to concentrate on.  You can see this by increasing the right side bound; on my system it works fine up to 19.32 but then has trouble.

```
> integrate(f, -Inf, 19.32)
2.506628 with absolute error < 3.7e-05
> integrate(f, -Inf, 19.33)
6.43579e-05 with absolute error < 0.00012
```

But why not use `pnorm`?

```
> pnorm(1e6)*sqrt(2*pi)
[1] 2.506628
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an excerpt from integrate help page:

> When integrating over infinite intervals do so explicitly, rather than
>   just using a large number as the endpoint. This increases the chance
>   of a correct answer – any function whose integral over an infinite
>   interval is finite must be near zero for most of that interval.

So the behaviour you get with R is a feature, not a bug. The function which you integrate is essentially zero outside interval $[-9,9]$ (the values are less than machine tolerance, `.Machine$double.eps`), so your case falls in to the situation described in the help page.